# Why my program doesn't print the wanted outcome?

Tags: java

2. Write a Java program that takes an input string and determines the number of consonants, vowels (‘y’ excluded), punctuation (‘.’, ‘,’ , ‘;’ , ‘!’ , ‘?’), and whitespace characters (‘\n’, ‘\t’, ‘ ’). Print the results to the console with reasonable clarity in output.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class a {

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        System.out.print("Enter: "); 
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);


        String input = scan.next(); 

        int whitespace = 0;
        int punctuation = 0;
        int consonants = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++){ 
            char ch= input.charAt(i);


            if (i == '.' || i == ',' || i == '!' || i == ';' || i =='?')
                punctuation++;

             if ((ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z') || (ch >= 'A' && ch <= 'Z'))  
                consonants++;
     
             else if (i == 'y' || i == 'Y')
                consonants--;

            else 
                whitespace++;
        } 
        System.out.println("Consonants: " + consonants);
        System.out.println("Punctuation: " + punctuation);
        System.out.println("White spaces: " + whitespace);



    }
}
```

```
Enter: yuuh.
Consonants: 4
Punctuation: 0
White spaces: 1
```

Comment: Use {} for your ifs.

Comment: Well, how can you expect to print a proper number of vowels if you do not have a variable that holds their number.

Comment: Why do you increment `consonants` when you find a vowel, and decrement `consonants` when you find *y*? That's not what you're being asked to do. Also, why do you sometimes check the character and sometimes its index?

Answer (score 1):

```
else if ( i== 'y' || i== 'Y')
             consonants--;
```

You are using i to check the character instead of ch.